# Alternate Realities Challenge - Rigging & Otherwise

Tags: rigging

I'm currently working on the Alternate Realities Challenge and I'm baffled by 2 things mainly that I cannot figure out:

**First:** Character Rigging: Whenever I rig a character (as shown in the images) the arms don't seem to work correctly. I've tried this with 1 Character I modeled and 2 I downloaded. I tried using Blender's "Rigify" and even using the original Meta-rig in the original .blend file and used it as a parent to my model (with Automatic Weights). I've almost finished the whole thing and I've spent more than 6 days now trying to figure this out.

**Second:** The Rope connecting the character and whatever he's pulling. Are there any useful tutorials or instructions on where to begin to understand how this is done?

Image Links:

https://ibb.co/804wwN9

https://ibb.co/WKZrRNs

https://ibb.co/djJPfdL

https://ibb.co/rtjwnsk

https://ibb.co/ZcDzZPD

**Note:** My experience in blender so far Blender Guru's Donut Model and CG Boost's beginner tutorial. Anything I applied in my scene I learned along the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.